# initializeLayout and asynchronous loading

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

Currently I'm loading data asynchronously via `data.js` as provided by the Grid app template. The problem exists where `groupedItems.js` (the "Hub" page) calls `_initializeLayout` in the `ready` handler before the `Data` in the global WinJS namespace is set due to the asynchronous nature of the StorageFile class.

In `data.js`:

```
fileNames.forEach(function (val, index, arr) {
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appx:///data/' + val + '.geojson');

    Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri).then(function (file) {

        Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file).then(function (contents) {

            // ... read, parse, and organize the data ...

            // Put the data into the global namespace
            WinJS.Namespace.define("Data", {
                items: groupedItems,
                groups: groupedItems.groups,
                getItemReference: getItemReference,
                getItemsFromGroup: getItemsFromGroup,
                resolveGroupReference: resolveGroupReference,
                resolveItemReference: resolveItemReference
            });
        });
    });
}
```

In `groupedItems.js`:

```
 // ...

 // This function updates the ListView with new layouts
    _initializeLayout: function (listView, viewState) {
        /// <param name="listView" value="WinJS.UI.ListView.prototype" />

        if (viewState === appViewState.snapped) {
            listView.itemDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
            listView.groupDataSource = null;
            listView.layout = new ui.ListLayout();
        } else {
            listView.itemDataSource = Data.items.dataSource;
            listView.groupDataSource = Data.groups.dataSource;
            listView.layout = new ui.GridLayout({ groupHeaderPosition: "top" });
        }
    },

 // ....
```

Seeing as I cannot move this code out of this file into the `done()` function of the Promise in `data.js`, how do I make the application wait until `Data` is initialized in the WinJS namespace prior to initializing the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two asynchronous operations in progress (loading of the data and loading of the page) and one action (initializing the grid) that needs to happen only after both asynchronous operations are complete (page is loaded, data is available).  There are a lot of approaches to solve this depending upon what architectural approach you want to take.

1. The brute force method is that you create a new function that checks to see if both the document is ready and the data is loaded and, if so, it calls `_initializeLayout()`.  You then call that function in both places (where the doc is loaded and when the data is available) and it will execute only when both conditions are satisfied.  It appears that you can tell if the data is loaded by checking for the existence of the global `Data` item and the its relevant properties.
2. There are more involved solutions that are architecturally a little cleaner.  For example, in your doc ready handler, you can check to see if the data is available yet.  If it is, you just initialize the layout.  If, not you install a notification so that when the data is available, your callback will get called and you can then initialize the layout.  If the data loading code doesn't currently have a notification scheme, then you create one that can be used by any client who wants to be called when the data has been loaded.  This has the advantage over the first method in that the data loading code doesn't have to know anything about the grid.  The grid does have to know about the data - which makes sense because the grid requires the data.
3. There are surely ways to use the promise/done system to do this too though I'm not personally familiar enough with it to suggest a good way to do it using that.

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on the "create a notification" scheme to execute a callback function, or provide some example of this?

Comment: In `data.js`, you could add a function called `notifyWhenDataReady(fn)` that takes a callback function as an argument.  Then, when the data is ready in `data.js`, it calls that callback (if one is registered).  In groupedItems, it checks to see if the data is already available.  If not, it installs the callback and defers calling `_initializeLayout()` until the callback is called.  This way, `data.js` doesn't have to know anything specifically about `_initializeLayout()` or `groupedItems.js`, but it can still provide the right information to those other modules when they need it.

Comment: The only problem I'm encountering with that is that the scope of `noficyWhenDataReady(fn)` is limited to `data.js`, so how am I supposed to pass the callback function argument fn?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 - you have to make `notifyWhenDataReady(fn)` callable from outside `data.js`.  There are a number of ways to do that.  Since I don't know the structure of `data.js`, I don't know what would be consistent with the way it is already written.  A simple global function (probably scoped to one of the namespaces already being used in `data.js`) would make sense to me, but the best answer would be to make it public that same way other functions in `data.js` are made public.

Comment: I'll try putting it after everything. Nothing in data.js is public, hence the use of the WinJS.Namespace to pass the data.